# Request header is always undefined in Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to send an https request to a cloud function I created in Firebase via the web client. 
Cloud functions code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.app = (req, res) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, X-Requested-With');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, OPTIONS, POST');

  console.log('authorization', req.get('authorization')); 
  res.status(200).send('authorization test');
};
```

Web client code:

```
const data = JSON.stringify('/*data to send here...*/');
const url = '/* url endpoint here */'

const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', () => {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        /* success */
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
});

xhr.open('POST', url);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', '/* auth token string here */');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
xhr.send(data);
```

In the firebase console logs for firebase functions, I'm always getting the authorization as undefined even though I'm sending the authorization token as explained in [Firebase verifyIdToken page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens).

Comment: same problem did you slove it?

Comment: @Ireiner, I didn't. I ditched `XHR` and used `fetch` with `Content-Type` to `application/json`. That fixed it for me.